# Jquery focus is not running without any error

Tags: jquery

Hello i just started learning Jquery and my below code is not working and its not even showing any error in console.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        var email_default = "Please enter email address..";

        $('input[type="email"]').attr('value', email_default);

        $(this).focus(function(){
            $(this).attr('value', '')
        });

     });
    </script>
```

The above script is not doing anything when i focus the input box. The same code is running in the video tutorial i am watching.

I need to know what is causing my function not working.

Thanks

Comment: `$(this)` is the window, why would you focus that, and it probably has no value ?

Comment: Why you don't want to use placeholder attribute so no javascript needed at all for this functionality?

Comment: It would be better to use the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute. Emptying the value whenever the user focuses on the field prevents him from editing a previously entered value. You should at least check whether the value is currently the default.

Comment: Acutually i am just learning.. i know the place holder can do this but just learning selectors.

Comment: Why $(this) is the window ? I've selected the input[type='email'] just in the above line. Shouldn't be $(this) now equals to input box ? @adeneo

Comment: $(this) is the window for line >> $(this).focus(function()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the value use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/), the value attribute is used only to set the initial value of an `input` element once that is done then you need to change the value property of the dom element.

In order to set the value of an input element jQuery has the utility method `.val()` which can be used for both setting and getting the value of the input

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var email_default = "Please enter email address..";
    $('input[type="email"]').val(email_default).focus(function () {
        $(this).val('')
    });
});
```

Also inside the ready handler `this` refers to the document object, not the email input, you need to assign the focus handler to the input element.

Also you might have a look at [html5 placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder)(for IE support you may have to use some plugins though).

Comment: I know that this can be done with the code you gave me. Actually the goal is to learn the attr selector that is why i am using it.

Comment: @user2812955 see the explanation above... if you want set it using the `.prop()` method like `.prop('value', 'sdf')`

Comment: yeah so the $(this) was doing problem. But can you please guide me a little bit. that how $(this) works .. I mean if i am working on the input selector why it is selection DOM as $this ? Thanks its working now

Comment: @user2812955 a starting point will be http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

Comment: Thanks alot. Will see that

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way to use HTML5 placeholders while you use INPUT TYPE EMAIL from HTML5.

So, in that way your HTML for this input becomes to something like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email_address"
 placeholder="Please enter email address...">
```

Comment: Thanks bro but i've mentioned there that it is just for learning purpose. I know this can be done with placeholder. Anyways thank you :)